# Can you static_assert a tuple has only one type satisfying a particular condition?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

This code gets the first tuple element satisfying a test (in this case, if it derives `Base`). **How can I static_assert that only one element satisfying that condition may exist?** (much like C++17's `std::get<class>` fails to compile if there exists more than one element of the provided typename.)

```
template<class...>
struct voider { using type = void; };

template<class...Ts>
using void_t = typename voider<Ts...>::type;

template<template<class...> class Test, class Tuple>
struct get_first_pass;

template<template<class...> class Test, class Tuple>
using get_first_pass_t = typename get_first_pass<Test, Tuple>::type;

template<template<class...> class, class, class...>
struct first_pass {};

template<template<class...> class Test, class T0, class...Ts>
struct first_pass<Test, std::enable_if_t<!Test<T0>::value>, T0, Ts...> :
  first_pass<Test, void, Ts...>
{};

template<template<class...> class Test, class T0, class...Ts>
struct first_pass<Test, std::enable_if_t<Test<T0>::value>, T0, Ts...> {
  using type = T0;
};

template<template<class...> class Test, template<class...> class Tuple, class...Ts>
struct get_first_pass<Test, Tuple<Ts...>> : first_pass<Test, void, Ts...>
{};

template<class Base>
struct is_derived_from {
  template<class Derived>
  using test = std::is_base_of<std::decay_t<Base>, std::decay_t<Derived>>;
};

template<class Base, class Tuple>
using get_first_derived =
  get_first_pass_t<is_derived_from<Base>::template test, Tuple>;

template<class Base, class Tuple>
auto get_from_base(Tuple&& tuple)
-> decltype(std::get< get_first_derived<Base, std::decay_t<Tuple>> >(
                                                  std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))) {
  return std::get< get_first_derived<Base, std::decay_t<Tuple>> >(
                                                  std::forward<Tuple>(tuple));
}
```

Comment: there should be only one type in the tuple or possibly many types out of which only one statisfies your test?

Comment: Correct, it is for a mediator pattern implementation. Only one handler may register to handle a specific request. Request handlers implement a common interface which serves as the `Base` of this test.

Comment: I mean you could actually write a meta function that expresses the condition by mapping each type to true_type or false_type, and then piggy back on `get` to extract `true_type`. If there isn't exactly one `true_type` it will fail.

Comment: Something like `((int)predicate_v<Ts> + ...) == 1` perhaps?

Comment: Also, for TMP questions especially, please specify C++ version... 17 brings a lot of changes and new techniques, but many people aren't using it yet.

Comment: @NirFriedman At a high level, I agree. I am just having trouble implementing it, as I still grow more familiar with TMP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure to understand what do you exactly want.

But I suppose that, if you write a "counter" as follows

```
// count is derived from
template <typename, typename>
struct count_idf : public std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0U>
 { };

template <typename Base, template <typename...> class C, typename ... Ts>
struct count_idf<Base, C<Ts...>>
   : public std::integral_constant<std::size_t,
     (is_derived_from<Base>::template test<Ts>::value + ...)>
 { };
```

you can add a `static_assert()` as follows in `get_from_base()`

```
template<class Base, class Tuple>
auto get_from_base(Tuple&& tuple)
-> decltype(std::get< get_first_derived<Base, std::decay_t<Tuple>> >(
                                                  std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))) {
  static_assert( 1U == count_idf<Base, std::decay_t<Tuple>>{}, 
                 "not one and only one" );
  return std::get< get_first_derived<Base, std::decay_t<Tuple>> >(
                                                  std::forward<Tuple>(tuple));
}
```

Comment: May not be the most reusable way to do it, but fits my case and my question perfectly. Accepted answer.

Comment: @nolan - do you mean "without C++17"? In a recursive way, I suppose. But not so simple and elegant. If you want, I'll try a C++14 way to do it

Comment: C++17 is fine, I only mean that portion. I’m asking because I cannot find that feature by search terms and what that translates to in past standards.

Comment: @nolan - that feature is "template fold" or "template folding" (not sure which is correct); it's a C++17 great and very useful addition to the language (IMHO) and, pre-C++17, the usual solution was a recursive one; see the super's answer for a common and good (as usual: IMHO) C++11/C++14 solution.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! “C++17 ellipses recursion thingy” was proving an unuseful google search

Answer (score 1):

Here is a less elegant, but C++11 compatible way of doing it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

struct foo {

};

struct bar : foo {

};

template <std::size_t N, typename... T>
struct check_tuple;

template <std::size_t N, typename First, typename... Rest>
struct check_tuple<N, First, Rest...> : check_tuple<N+std::is_base_of<foo, First>::value , Rest...> {};

template <std::size_t N, typename First>
struct check_tuple<N, First> : check_tuple<N+std::is_base_of<foo, First>::value> {};

template <std::size_t N>
struct check_tuple<N> : std::false_type {};

template <>
struct check_tuple<1> : std::true_type {};

template <typename Types>
struct check_tuple_types;

template <typename... Types>
struct check_tuple_types<std::tuple<Types...>> : check_tuple<0, Types...> {};

int main() {
    std::cout << check_tuple_types<std::tuple<int, long, bar>>::value;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: not tried but... just to simplify a little... maybe, instead of `std::conditional<std::is_base_of<foo, First>::value, check_tuple<N+1, Rest...>,  check_tuple<N, Rest...>>::type`, could work `check_tuple<N+std::is_base_of<foo, First>::value, Rest...>`. And the same for the following conditional.

Comment: @max66 That is better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you and your code correctly then this specialisation is for when a type `T0` passes your test:

```
template<template<class...> class Test, class T0, class...Ts>
struct first_pass<Test, std::enable_if_t<Test<T0>::value>, T0, Ts...> {
  using type = T0;
};
```

So you've found one type that passes your test and now you want to make sure there's no type in `Ts` that also passes your test? If yes, then you can add the following utility:

```
template <bool... bs>
struct any_of : public std::false_type {  };

template <bool b, bool... bs>
struct any_of<b, bs...> : 
    public std::conditional_t<b, std::true_type, any_of<bs...>> {  };
```

And then use it:

```
template<template<class...> class Test, class T0, class...Ts>
struct first_pass<Test, std::enable_if_t<Test<T0>::value>, T0, Ts...> {
  static_assert(!any_of<Test<Ts>::value...>::value, 
                "multiple types pass the test");

  using type = T0;
};
```

Also, I'm not familiar with C++17 so consider this a pre-C++17 approach (of using your already existing code).

Answer (score 0):

```
#define RETURNS(...) \
  noexecpt(noexecpt(__VA_ARGS__)) \
  -> decltype( __VA_ARGS__ ) \
  { return __VA_ARGS__; }

template<class F>
constexpr auto foreacher( F&& f ) {
  return [f=std::forward<F>(f)](auto&&...args)mutable
    RETURNS( ((void)f( decltype(args)(args) ),...) )
}
```

foreacher takes a function and returns a function that takes any number of arguments and evaluates the result on each.

```
template<class T, class F>
constexpr std::size_t count_on_tuple( F&& f, T&& t ) {
  std::size_t n = 0;
  std::apply(
    foreacher([&](auto&& x) {
      if(f( decltype(x)(x)))
        ++n;
    }),
    std::forward<T>(t)
  );
  return n;
}
```

now you just need a function object to feed this:

```
template<class Base>
constexpr auto is_derived_from_f = [](auto&& Derived) {
 return std::is_base_of< std::decay_t<Base>, std::decay_t<decltype(Derived)> >{};
};

template<class Base>
constexpr auto exactly_one_derived_from_f = [](auto&& Tuple) {
  return count_on_tuple( is_derived_from_f<Base>, decltype(Tuple)(Tuple) ) == 1;
};
```

this can be covnerted back to a trait if you really want to.